# Interactivity of mapbox markers/points depending on the rendering method selected

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-marker

AFAIK, when plotting markers on mapbox map (Mapbox GL JS), you have two options:

**(a)** to plot them as point and layer styles (in which case they are rendered into the final `<canvas>` element, they are not inspectable, they cannot receive :hover states

**(b)** to add them as markers, which then remain individually inspectable HTML elements. The downside of this method though is that they don't zoom/scale as smoothly and quickly as the map so that a little of inertia is noticable.

Both methods support interaction (if you supply `interactive: true` in the **(a)** option) although you handle it in different ways.

Are there any other limitations of any of those methods that I should consider when building interactive map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a pretty broad question. But generally I see the upsides of each method as:

- Layers: part of the map, so you get collision detection, data-driven styling, zoom-driven styling, etc.
- Markers: part of the DOM, so you get CSS, Javascript events, easy integration of images and fonts, and simpler mouse event handling, like `:hover`.

It's not quite true to say that layers don't support `:hover`. You can detect `mouseOver` then do `map.setFeatureState()` to set a hover property on the feature. It's just that you don't get it for free.

Comment: Right. I have used that setFeatureState method today. Works great. It's only that css transitions are unavailable if you want to emphasize selecting a marker with a short glow effect, for example. Or am I wrong again? ;)

Comment: I think you could probably achieve that. Mapbox-gl-js does support animated transitions but you have to do it quite indirectly. Feel free to ask another question about them.